# remove rule from RelativeLayout before api 17

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

Prior to API 17, how do I remove a rule from a layout? I have a RelativeLayout with a number of children. The RelativeLayout is the main layout of my activity. After adding the rule programmatically using

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layout = (LayoutParams) theChild.getLayoutParams();
layout.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
```

I need to remove the rule programmatically at some later time. How would I do this assuming earlier API than 17?

Answer (score 162):

Ah, I figure it out.

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layout = (LayoutParams) myChild.getLayoutParams();
layout.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, 0);
```

So there is really no removeRule until API 17.

Comment: This answer wasn't immediately clear to me.  In Android code, removeRule(rule) basically does the same thing as addRule(rule, 0), which is why the answer shown here works.

Comment: @Cote Mounyo but this code now in AS required api level19 how to do in api level below o equal to 16

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the situation, in my case I created new `LayoutParams` and then added rules which were needed